# Does loadHtmlFile php function sends ip address of the web server to the target website server?

Tags: php

Suppose my website is mywebsite.com and collecting data from remotewebsite.com

I am using loadHtmlFile function to load data from a remote website. The page I am accessing is dynamic and I am calling loadHtmlFile every 3 seconds to get the updated data via ajax call. My concern is, the website owner should not know I am scanning his/her page from my host server ip address.

But the loadHtmlFile script is called from my server only when any visitor visits mywebsite.com.

i) which ip is sent to remotewebsite.com owner? my server ip or the visitors ip who is vising mywebsite.com?
ii) How can I hide myself as I am scanning their site? is there any risk what I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your own server IP will most likely appear in the remote site's server logfiles. With Apache it is the access log.

I am not sure about hiding yourself. There's proxy servers for this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server.

Comment: I agree above...If data you are pulling is not changing much or cacheable then at least you can cache the incoming data so that you don't have to go their server every time or very often...If the remote site has a high traffic then they probably will never find you by going there every 3 seconds.